# Storing SUDO Log files in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, sudo

We want to store all the sudo io log files in elastic. We are defining the schema for it but not sure how the data from TTYIN, TTYOUT, STDIN, STDOUT , STDERR can be stored for each session. 
we are thinking each of these files to be a column in the schema and every row is represented by a unique TSID (sudo session id).
how can the data from TTYIN, TTYOUT, STDIN, STDOUT , STDERR can be parsed and stored in ElasticSearch?
Any pointers on schema definition from SUDO I/O logging perspective would be of help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Auditbeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/auditbeat), which uses the Auditd rules and can ship the events directly to Elasticsearch.

I think the rules for su / sudo you want to configure are this (they will all be stored under the key `elevated-privs`):

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/su -F key=elevated-privs
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/su -F key=elevated-privs
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setresuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo -F key=elevated-privs
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setresuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo -F key=elevated-privs
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -F key=elevated-privs
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -F key=elevated-privs
```